# Can't restore mysqldump database backup in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: backup, mysqldump, restore, ubuntu

I'm trying to restore a database backup created using mysqldump. If I do:

```
    $ mysqldump -u ROOT -p DATABASE_NAME < DATABASE.SQL
```

the database remains empty, even though I get some screen output and the line "Dump completed...", followed by a timestamp. I could not spot any error messages in the output

I made sure I quit MySQL before attempting the restore and I have tried to include the password in the command line, with no success. However, if I try:

```
    mysql>source /path_to_dump_file/DATABASE.SQL
```

it works just fine.

Any thoughts?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
mysql -u ROOT -p DATABASE_NAME < DATABASE.SQL
```

instead of

```
mysqldump -u ROOT -p DATABASE_NAME < DATABASE.SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

To IMPORT:

ype the following command to import sql data file:

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql
```

In this example, import 'data.sql' file into 'blog' database using vivek as username:

```
$ mysql -u sat -p -h localhost blog < data.sql
```

If you have a dedicated database server, replace localhost hostname with with actual server name or IP address as follows:

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h 202.54.1.10 databasename < data.sql
```

OR use hostname such as mysql.cyberciti.biz

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h mysql.cyberciti.biz database-name < data.sql
```

If you do not know the database name or database name is included in sql dump you can try out something as follows:

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h 202.54.1.10 < data.sql
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html

If you want a GUI tool then you could probably use navicat for this.